# I need to enable more users on my app side to receive data from an other application from all those users

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object and a set instance of it:

```
var obj = new Object()
obj.userId  = "ABC"
```

There's an ID field in my application (called, for example, 'myApp'), clicking on which fires up another application, named 'abcApp'.

I need to login and complete some task on abcApp through user "ABC". After completing the task a number N will be sent from abcApp to myApp.

N is visible in my application when it's generated by user "ABC". However I need this number to be visible in myApp when abcApp is logged using other user ids, say, "PQR", "XYZ" etc.

How can I do this in the front end code as written above?

Comment: Are the websites hosted on the same domain? If not then you will need to transfer data between servers, and this is not a front-end only task.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the websites are hosted on different domains. How can I solve this ?

Comment: is writing `obj.userId="ABC","PQR", "XYZ"` correct syntactically? I can't test the above functionality as one application when I am writing code is locally deployed.

Comment: If they're on different domains then you will need to do this server side. There is no way for the front-end of two separate sites to communicate directly.

Comment: `is writing obj.userId="ABC","PQR", "XYZ" correct syntactically?` No, as you can't assign multiple values to a single property. I'd suggest using an array in that case: `obj.userId = ["ABC","PQR", "XYZ"]`